# Conditional Formatting based on Cell Text

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have the data in the columns ABCD in one sheet and a pivot based on that data on another. I want to conditional format my pivot table values based on the value of the `Color` column in my data sheet using VBA.

What is the Rule that I will need to create here? I recall we can use `Name Manager` for this purpose, but I am not sure how to?

[image]

Comment: You can loop through each value and use `SWITCH` to color them one by one. Or, if your values are static just create the standards rules right in excel... If value = 0 then Green. If your unique combinations of colors is long then this route is less ideal

Comment: Unfortunately, the values are not static, and that is why you will see a negative can be Red or Yellow. As of now, I want to know what formula I can input in the `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` for conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `VLOOKUP` and create 3 rules with the following formulas:

```
=VLOOKUP(G$2,$A:$D,4)="red"

=VLOOKUP(G$2,$A:$D,4)="yellow"

=VLOOKUP(G$2,$A:$D,4)="green"
```

And match each condition with the appropriate colour